# How I make this kind of Select in MySql?

Tags: mysql, select-query

I have a table and it looks like this,

```
mysql> select * from match_info;
+---------------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------+
| match_info_id | user_id | body_types | hair_colors | ethnicity |
+---------------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------+
|             1 |       1 | 1,5,9,13   | 1,5,9,13    | 2,6,10    |
|             2 |       2 | 1,5,9,13   | 5           | 1,5,9     |
+---------------+---------+------------+-------------+-----------+
```

I have used lookup tables for `body_types`, `hair_colors` and `ethnicity` with `id` and `name` columns in each table.

Using above I need to select all values for particular user. Like this.

From body_type table.

Body Type: `Skinny, Muscular, Large, Ripped`

Hair Color: `Blonde, Dark Brown, Strawberry Blonde, Dark Blonde` etc....

Can anybody tell me how I make a select query to get result as above.

Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: Your database design would be easier to handle in standard ways if you normalized it by including many-to-many join tables between the `body_types`, `hair_colors`, and `ethnicity` and the user.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, Is there a way to get a result as above instead  of changing database design? Thank you.

Comment: Almost certainly. But fighting a relational database to avoid normalization tends to make things harder in a lot of ways. So unless you have serious, *specifically-identifiable and benchmarked* performance reasons for doing it this way, you should probably reconsider your design.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, Actually I am not sure how to change my table design. Can you kindly help me? Thank you...

Comment: I would recommend looking up resources on the keywords I mentioned: normalization and many-to-many/join tables. It's a fairly broad field, but there's a lot of good guidance out there, because it's crucial for almost any database design to understand normalization (and when to denormalize).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables and put `find_in_set` function at on clause.
Try this :

```
select t.match_info_id, t.user_id,
    group_concat(distinct a.name) as body_types,
    group_concat(distinct b.name) as hair_colors,
    group_concat(distinct c.name) as ethnicity
from match_info as t
    inner join body_type as a on find_in_set(a.id,t.body_types)
    inner join hair_color as b on find_in_set(b.id,t.hair_colors)
    inner join ethnicity as c on find_in_set(c.id,t.ethnicity)
group by t.match_info_id, t.user_id
```

Please note that you can use `left join` instead of `inner join` depending on your needs.